# How to implement BFS algorithm for pacman?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, maze, pacman, breadth-first-search

I'm implementing AI for pacman in a maze world using search algorithms like DFS , BFS , UCS and A* . the implementing for DFS is very simple, but for BFS I'm mixed up. I don't know how to implement it , because I can't understand how could it possible that pacman start from a location and enqueue its neighbor's location and check them and go through to them. :/ can anyone help me? !

Comment: BFS is shortest path solver, I suspect you are looking for TSP (Pacman needs to eat the dots?)

Comment: no,the question is pacman should goes to the goal location using BFS algorithm.

Comment: So, where are you struggling with? BFS solves that easily.\

Comment: but how? in DFS pacman goes through the path and when there is no possible move pacman returns to find out a possible move and so on. but in BFS pacman checks its neighbors and enqueue them but in many diffrent paths. can u help me how to implement it, if it's so simple? :/ thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BFS, you traverse the algorithm and discover a shortest path to each node.

In order to get this path later on, you need to store `parent:V->V`, in other words, you need to "remember" from which cell you got to the current one. This is easily done by storing a dictionary/map, where the key is a cell, and the value is the cell you used to discover the key.

In pseudo code:

```
BFS(source, target):
   queue = empty new queue
   queue.add(source)
   parent= new dictionary
   parent.add(source, None)
   while (queue.empty() == false): 
      curr = queue.dequeue()
      if (curr == target)
          return getPath(dict, curr)
      for each neighbor u of curr:
          if u is not a key in parent:
             parent[u] = curr
             queue.add(u)
```

The above BFS fills the `parent` dictionary, and the path is returned by the following getPath() function, which basically traverses the dictionary until it finds the "root" (which is the original source node).

```
getPath(dict, target):
   sol = [] //empty list
   curr = target
   while curr != None:
         sol.addFirst(curr)
         curr = dict.get(curr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the shortest path, you have to memorize the already visited positions, because the shortest path will use all its positions only once.

Here is a simplified version of the algorithm:

```
Q := an empty queue of positions
V := an empty set of already visited positions
Q.pushBack( initial position )
While Q is not empty:
    current_position := Q.popFront()
    If current_position == goal_position:
        Return "You won!"
    If current_position Is Not In V:
        Q.pushBack( NeighboursOf(current_position) )
```

I used a very simple state, holding only the position.
But if you want a full algorithm, your state must contain the position plus the path to this position. And when you compare two states, just compare the positions, not the path.